# divide list and generate series of new lists. one from each list and rest into other

Tags: python, list

I have three lists and want to sort and generate two new list. Can any one please tell how it can be done?

```
list1=[12,25,45], list2=[14,69], list3=[54,98,68,78,48]
```

I want to print the output like

```
chosen1=[12,14,54], rest1=[25,45,69,98,68,78,48]
chosen2=[12,14,98], rest2=[25,45,69,54,68,78,48]
```

and so on 
(every possible combination for chosen list)

I have tried to write this but I don't know

```
list1=[12,25,45]
list2=[14,69]
list3=[54,98,68,78,48]
for i in xrange (list1[0],list1[2]):
for y in xrange(list2[0], list2[1]):
for z in xrange(list[0],list[4])
      for a in xrange(chosen[0],[2])
chosed1.append()
for a in xrange(chosen[0],[7])
rest1.append()
Print rest1
Print chosen1
```

Comment: You want all possible two digit combinations in the first and the rest in the second?

Comment: Please show your attempts. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: what is the basis for the items in the chosen list? random?

Comment: NO, it should be like, chosen1 will contain first item of every list and then chosen2 will have first item from two list but second item of third list.and so on .I tried nested loop, but got completely puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.product` generates all permutations of selecting one thing each out of different sets of things:

```
import itertools

list1 = [12,25,45]
list2 = [14,69]
list3 = [54,98,68,78,48]

for i,(a,b,c) in enumerate(itertools.product(list1,list2,list3),1):
    # Note: Computing rest this way will *not* work if there are duplicates
    #       in any of the lists.
    rest1 = [n for n in list1 if n != a]
    rest2 = [n for n in list2 if n != b]
    rest3 = [n for n in list3 if n != c]
    rest = ','.join(str(n) for n in rest1+rest2+rest3)
    print('chosen{0}=[{1},{2},{3}], rest{0}=[{4}]'.format(i,a,b,c,rest))
```

Output:

```
chosen1=[12,14,54], rest1=[25,45,69,98,68,78,48]
chosen2=[12,14,98], rest2=[25,45,69,54,68,78,48]
chosen3=[12,14,68], rest3=[25,45,69,54,98,78,48]
chosen4=[12,14,78], rest4=[25,45,69,54,98,68,48]
chosen5=[12,14,48], rest5=[25,45,69,54,98,68,78]
chosen6=[12,69,54], rest6=[25,45,14,98,68,78,48]
chosen7=[12,69,98], rest7=[25,45,14,54,68,78,48]
chosen8=[12,69,68], rest8=[25,45,14,54,98,78,48]
chosen9=[12,69,78], rest9=[25,45,14,54,98,68,48]
chosen10=[12,69,48], rest10=[25,45,14,54,98,68,78]
chosen11=[25,14,54], rest11=[12,45,69,98,68,78,48]
chosen12=[25,14,98], rest12=[12,45,69,54,68,78,48]
chosen13=[25,14,68], rest13=[12,45,69,54,98,78,48]
chosen14=[25,14,78], rest14=[12,45,69,54,98,68,48]
chosen15=[25,14,48], rest15=[12,45,69,54,98,68,78]
chosen16=[25,69,54], rest16=[12,45,14,98,68,78,48]
chosen17=[25,69,98], rest17=[12,45,14,54,68,78,48]
chosen18=[25,69,68], rest18=[12,45,14,54,98,78,48]
chosen19=[25,69,78], rest19=[12,45,14,54,98,68,48]
chosen20=[25,69,48], rest20=[12,45,14,54,98,68,78]
chosen21=[45,14,54], rest21=[12,25,69,98,68,78,48]
chosen22=[45,14,98], rest22=[12,25,69,54,68,78,48]
chosen23=[45,14,68], rest23=[12,25,69,54,98,78,48]
chosen24=[45,14,78], rest24=[12,25,69,54,98,68,48]
chosen25=[45,14,48], rest25=[12,25,69,54,98,68,78]
chosen26=[45,69,54], rest26=[12,25,14,98,68,78,48]
chosen27=[45,69,98], rest27=[12,25,14,54,68,78,48]
chosen28=[45,69,68], rest28=[12,25,14,54,98,78,48]
chosen29=[45,69,78], rest29=[12,25,14,54,98,68,48]
chosen30=[45,69,48], rest30=[12,25,14,54,98,68,78]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my Lists doesn't contain any duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to get 2 digit combinations from the two list and the remaining then this would be the solution:

```
import itertools
list1 = [12,25,45]
list2 = [14,69]
list3 = [21,34,56,32]
chosen = []
leftover = []
mergedlist = list(set(list1 + list2 + list3)) 
mergedNewList = [x for x in itertools.permutations(mergedlist,3)]
for i,value in enumerate(mergedNewList):
    chosen.append(list(value))
    leftover.append([j for j in mergedlist if j not in chosen[i]])
    print chosen[i]
    print leftover[i]`
```

I have appended the values in a single variable for `chosen` and for the rest in `leftover` as this is the most pythonic way of storing the values.